# Series where Earth kicked out of alien club, then invited back because we are savage

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space-exploration

Copying from a Reddit post last year where someone looked for the same:

"...book where the human race made contact with a galactic race, part of a group of civilizations in the galaxy. Earth wanted to join, but is kicked out because of their aggressiveness and inclination for violence. Earth loses the capacity to have interstellar travel and are trapped in our own solar system. Few time later, one of the civilizations come knocking on Earth's door asking for help because intergalactic war started. Earth accepts the call, but they send criminals to help with the war."

Anybody know this?

Comment: Could it be [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58353/short-story-where-the-earth-has-been-kept-inside-a-force-field-for-millennia)?

Comment: @user14111 - That was my first thought as well.

Comment: The OP says looking for a SERIES, and there were no criminals sent to help fight a war in "With friends like these"

Comment: Would this be a trilogy, the third part having a title something along the lines of "The False Mirror" in which the enemy starts using cloned humans against the earth soldiers?

Comment: The trilogy I was thinking of is ["The Damned Trilogy"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Damned_Trilogy) by Alan Dean Foster, but the humans weren't criminals, so that may not be it.